# How can I combine an initial angular velocity and angular acceleration to obtain a final rotation?

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra, physics, quaternions

I am attempting to model the rotation of a soccer ball for a game I'm working on. Specifically, I have the initial rotation as a quaternion and the initial angular velocity and angular acceleration in X, Y, Z components. I would like to create a function that will use this information to return the resulting rotation after *t* seconds.

The challenge is that the ball may have a spin on it, causing the initial angular velocity to be about a different axis than the angular acceleration. In other words, the axis of rotation for the instantaneous angular velocity changes with time.

The "easy" solution here is to simply calculate and apply the instantaneous angular velocity in small time increments to approximate the result, but I would like to avoid this in favour of a more efficient and accurate solution if possible.

My first thought was to try applying the angular acceleration (by multiplying with *t<sup>2</sup>*) and initial angular velocity (by multiplying with *t*) separately, but of course that does not work because the two affect the ball simultaneously, not one before the other.

Is there any way I can combine the initial angular velocity and acceleration for an exact result, or is discrete time stepping my only option? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question fits better at https://physics.stackexchange.com/. Once you have the formulas just code them.

Comment: Thanks @Ripi2, I'll move this over there.

For anyone here in the future, it looks like discrete evolution is the way to go: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/770408